# Execute and Wait not working sometimes

Tags: delphi, wait, execute

I am using this code I found on the Internet and on some devices it waits, but on others it does not. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong. My app loads in Truecrypt and then waits for the user to enter the password. On exiting Truecrypt, it then launches my menu-program.

My Lenovo Miix 2 8" tablet, win8.1 (all up to date) will wait, my Dad's win8.0 (all up to date) will wait, but my friend's ASUS M80TA 8" win8.1 tablet (all up to date) will not. Another friend's win7 laptop (all up to date) does not wait ether.

```
var
  aTSI : TStartupInfo;
  aTPI : TProcessInformation;
  iRet : Integer;
  ExitCode: Cardinal;
begin
  FillChar(aTSI, SizeOf(aTSI), #0);
  FillChar(aTPI, SizeOf(aTPI), #0);
  aTSI.CB:=SizeOf(aTSI);
  if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(sEXE), nil, nil, False,
                       NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       nil, nil, aTSI, aTPI) then
    RaiseLastWin32Error;
  repeat
    iRet:=MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, aTPI.hProcess,
    False, INFINITE, (QS_ALLINPUT));
    if iRet <> (WAIT_OBJECT_0) then
      Application.ProcessMessages;
  until iRet = (WAIT_OBJECT_0); // use this for normal programs
  ExitCode:= 0;
  if not GetExitCodeProcess(aTPI.hProcess, ExitCode) then
    RaiseLastWin32Error;
  Result:= ExitCode;
  CloseHandle(aTPI.hProcess);
end;
```

Comment: Hard to say. Have you done any debugging? Add trace logging. Also the code leaks at least one, and sometimes two handles. Do you understand the code at all? If not then this is going to be painful.

Comment: Is this code in a worker thread ? Waiting *loop* with `QS_ALLINPUT` flag combined with `ProcessMessages` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Also, it should be calling `Application.ProcessMessages` only when `iRet = (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1)`, not when `iRet <> WAIT_OBJECT_0`. And `RaiseLastWin32Error` has been deprecated for a LONG time, use `RaiseLastOSError` instead. And use `try/finally` to make sure the handles are always closed whether an exception is raised or not.

Answer (score 0):

The likely explanation is as follows:

1. You call CreateProcess which creates a new process and returns a handle to that process.
2. That first new process in turn starts a different process, and immediately returns. That second process is the one that you see, and believe to be the process that you created.
3. Your wait on the first process handle returns.

In order to know how to deal with this you'd need to supply some details about the process that you are attempting to start. As to why the code works on some machines and not others, that would likely be down to the implementation details of the target application, the external application that you are starting. Presumably it differs from machine to machine.

Looking at the code, it always leaks the thread handle returned in `aTPI.hThread`. And it leaks `aTPI.hProcess` if `GetExitCodeProcess` fails.

You also need to ensure that the string you pass to the command line argument of `CreateProcess` is an editable string, and not a literal that is stored in read-only memory.

It is also pointless to initialise `ExitCode` and then immediately overwrite it. What's more you can remove the `ExitCode` variable and pass `Result` directly to `GetExitCodeProcess`.

Your code also fails to acknowledge an error being returned by the wait function.

I'd probably write it like this:

```
function ExecAndWait(CommandLine: string): DWORD;
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  iRet: Integer;
begin
  UniqueString(CommandLine);
  si := Default(TStartupInfo);
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  Win32Check(CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, False, 
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, si, pi));
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  try
    while True do
    begin
      iRet := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, pi.hProcess, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
      Win32Check(iRet <> WAIT_FAILED);
      case iRet of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        break;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;
    end;
    Win32Check(GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, Result));
  finally
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

On my machine, when I pass `'notepad.exe'` to this function, the function does not return until the Notepad process is closed.

On the other hand, if I pass `'explorer.exe'` to the process, then the function returns immediately. What happens here is that a new explorer process starts, but it detects that one is already running, and asks that process to open a new window. The newly started explorer process immediately terminates.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the leaking bit so will study the code comparing your changes. The ExitCode was initialized as Delphi showed a warning "ExitCode may not have been initialized" I had tried using Result ddirectly, but got an error about "Formal and var parameters must be equal," but I now realize that was because the function was declared Integer and not DWord. Lots to learn. :) In all cases the machines are running the same app before the "wait" and after the "wait."

Comment: Don't expect the code in the answer to change the wait behaviour. It won't. As I tried to explain you have to dig deeper

Comment: Thanks, I understood that, but it returns a windows 998 error, "invalid access to memory". I am going to quit on this for now. Thanks anyway as it is getting weirder. Using the original code and Notepad as the first application to run and wait, it doesn't wait on any devices. Something to do with the app being launched as well. Will have to check windows Compatibility and Security settings.

Comment: I am guessing `GetExitCodeProcess()` is the one returning 998. Remember that it is returning an **exit code**, not an **error code**.  The meaning is app-specific, it could be anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "thanks anyway". Anyway what. You asked why the function was starting apps but returning before the app closed. What other explanation could there be?