# Pause the program until an external program exits

Tags: delphi

I am writing some code to restore backups. For that I use an external program. User can select more than one file and I will execute the external program for each file inside a `for` loop. How can I pause my program until the external program exits before restoring the next file?

Comment: Look at `CreateProcess()` and `WaitForSingleObject()`. `CreateProcess()` returns a process handle that you can wait on until the spawned process terminates.

Comment: Or just try to search
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181231/execute-and-wait-not-working-sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Here an example using CreateProcess() and WaitForSingleObject()

```
procedure RunaAndWait(Command:String);
var
  fStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  fProcessInformation: TProcessInformation;
  fProgram: String;
begin
  fProgram := trim(Command);
  FillChar(fStartupInfo, SizeOf(fStartupInfo), 0);
  with fStartupInfo do
  begin
    cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  end;

  if CreateProcess(nil, pchar(fProgram), nil, nil, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
    nil, nil, fStartupInfo, fProcessInformation) then
  begin
    while WaitForSingleObject(fProcessInformation.hProcess, 10) > 0 do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
    CloseHandle(fProcessInformation.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(fProcessInformation.hThread);
  end
  else
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;
```

Usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RunaAndWait('notepad.exe');
  Showmessage('Finished');
end;
```

Comment: here is an example of [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) which is wrong :D

Comment: ProcessMessages is problematic. Why do you call it?